# Is it possible to have a GET access to private S3 files based on domain or IP?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a private bucket in S3. I am able to upload files in S3, but when I want to view / download file, I get a "Access Denied".

Right now, I have no way to use signedURL.

I would like to allow to download my file based on my server IP / Domain. Is it possible to manage it at a bucket policy level ? All I found in internet converted my bucket into public, which is not what I want.

Comment: How are the files being served? Are they being served directly via the browser or are you downloading them privately onto the server?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have to investigate the component I'm using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you're wanting to use it the following options are available to you.

**Signed Cookies**

If you're trying to restrict access to assets unless someone is publically accessing your website the idea solution would be to add CloudFront in front of your S3 bucket (preferably using an origin for S3 and another for your application but all under the same domain).

Once you go with this approach you could make use of [Signed Cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html) which would enforce that at minimum that the user accessed via a safe signer. Unlike signed URLs this is done once and does not affect the existing codebase (no custom URLs for assets).

**Referer Header**

Whilst not ideal you can use the referer header either as a condition to the bucket policy or as a [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) rule when attached to a CloudFront distribution. To be clear this is **just a header** which is able to be set by anyone. If any of the information is sensitive then do not use this option.

More information about this option is available in the [How to Prevent Hotlinking by Using AWS WAF, Amazon CloudFront, and Referer Checking](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-hotlinking-by-using-aws-waf-amazon-cloudfront-and-referer-checking/) documentation.

**VPC Gateway Endpoint**

The preferred method to keeping your S3 bucket private **if** the only communication to S3 is via the instance connecting to the S3 APIs (such as via the SDK or CLI). This will not work if you are serving content to the user publicly in the browser from S3.

By creating a [gateway endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html) for S3 you can the create a condition in the S3 bucket policy for `aws:SourceVpce` which will allow you to restrict the `GetObject` action to only this connection.

**IP Address**

Just as you can whitelist by a `referer` header you can whitelist via a source IP address. This option is only appropriate where the source accessing the object is a fixed IP address, an example is an EC2 instance connecting outbound via a NAT. If you are running a public website and the asset is served in the browser, this option is not viable as the IP needing to be whitelisted would be the clients not the servers.

This can be performed either via either a bucket policy using the `IpAddress` condition or by attaching an [IPSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_IPSet.html) to a WAF that is attached to CloudFront.

**Summary**

The above are all options available with some preferred over others. It will all depend how you use S3, and its possible that you can use multiple of these to lock it down further.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly use [aws:Referer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-referer) as shown in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4):

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this is rather easily circumvented protection, and should not be relied upon for absolute security:

> aws:referer **should not be used to prevent unauthorized parties** from making direct AWS requests. It is offered only to allow customers to protect their digital content, such as content stored in Amazon S3, from being referenced on unauthorized third-party sites.

Comment: I did it yesturday, but found out I bucket was public after applying this policy...

Comment: @Juliatzin Of course its public, just limited to the given referrer. If you don't want to use pre-singed URL, the only other option is to server your files though CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if we have all the details to know what your issues are, e.g. do you have ownership of the bucket, etc.

Given you ask about IP whitelisting, here is a guide about that:
https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/5761/how-to-whitelist-ip-addresses-to-access-an-aws-s3-bucket/

So yes, it all should be possible if you have the necessary ownership over the s3

Answer (score -2):

You can use the NotIpAddress condition to limit specific IP addresses to the bucket. If you are still getting the access denied check that the contents of the files are not being encrypted with a KMS key, this will stop the user from downloading files through the UI if you do not have permission to access the KMS key.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
     "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
         "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
     "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: NotIpAddress doesn't mean it is a blackList ?

Comment: The following example denies permissions to any user to perform any Amazon S3 operations on objects in the specified S3 bucket unless the request originates from the range of IP addresses specified in the condition. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: It is more like a whitelist deny everything but allow this IP

Comment: This policy will deny even authenticated access, unless it comes from that IP range. The goal is to allow *unauthenticated* access from a specific IP (i.e. allow `s3:GetObject` from a specific IP). Quite different.

Comment: There is no talk about authenticated / unauthenticated access in his question

Comment: The OP appears to want to be able to download from a specific IP without having to make the bucket public. I'm not sure how you'd read that any other way. Your policy would be a potential disaster and might completely block access, even from the AWS console.

Comment: @Jarmod you are wrong that is from the AWS documentation. It is a best practice to have a private bucket with publicly accessible objects that can only be accessed using the NotIpAddress to limit only that server access.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3) shows you an example of how to write a policy that restricts all (and I do mean *all*) client access to a specific IP range, if that's the functionality that you want. That means, for example, that even if you want to modify the bucket policy, you can only do it from that IP range. That's a very unusual policy, in practice. From my reading of the original OP request, it's also not relevant to the question.

Comment: I used this policy, but I even lost access to aws from my browser. Had to use aws-cli on my server to delete the bucket policy. You should specify actions.

Comment: @jarmod the user juliatzin states it must be used for a specific IP it does not say it still needs to be public for everyone.

Comment: I'll try one last time, because I'm patient ;-) and this is worth understanding. If you work with AWS infrastructure in any way and you suggest applying this policy to your client's buckets then you are almost certainly going to cause problems. When someone asks for help to "allow access from IP address X", the solution should not be a policy that "restricts all access to IP address X", which is what you've proposed. Those two things are not logically equivalent. Also, I didn't supply an answer to the question, so I'm not in competition with you here.